# Is it possible to split XMLGregorianCalendar value?

Tags: java, split, gregorian-calendar

I have the below method,

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(String s) 
        throws ParseException, 
                DatatypeConfigurationException
    {
    XMLGregorianCalendar result = null;
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar;
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                    date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);        
                    gregorianCalendar = 
                        (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                    gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);
                    result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
                    return result;
    }
```

It returns me `2014-04-29T13:22:51.000+05:30` but i dont want the timezone part and the milliseconds part as well. Is it possible to split its value and get it like `2014-04-29T13:22:51` . Any suggestion?

Comment: You have to add this after you assign `result` and just before you return it. `result.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the timezone field part as undefined after you assign value to the result.

```
....
result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
result.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
return result;
```